# How to set up a locale in ZF2 from browser preferences?

Tags: translation, zend-framework2

In Zend framework 1 I can do

```php
try {
    $locale = new Zend_Locale('browser'); 
} catch (Zend_Locale_Exception $e) {
    $locale = new Zend_Locale('en');   
}
$registry = Zend_Registry::getInstance();
$registry->set('Zend_Locale', $locale);
```

But how does it work with Zend Framework 2?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Judging from this [RFC](http://framework.zend.com/wiki/display/ZFDEV2/RFC+-+i18n+layer), the decision was taken to leave Zend_Locale out of Zend Framework 2 and rely on the core [PHP I18n classes](http://us.php.net/intl).

I would recommend reading the manual starting with the [introduction](http://us.php.net/manual/en/intro.intl.php) to get a good understanding of the classes and then refactoring your code to use them.

Comment: So i tired to use \Locale::acceptFromHttp($this->request->getHeader()); and i have an error Fatal error: Class 'Locale' not found in ...

Comment: This means that you do not have the intl extension running. Locate your php.ini for 'intl' and enable it or contact your host (if youre on any hoster)

Comment: You obviously didn't read the manual through as I suggested. You need to read this page http://us.php.net/manual/en/intl.installation.php

Comment: This extension is bundled with PHP as of PHP version 5.3.0. Alternatively, the PECL version of this extension may be used with all PHP versions greater than 5.2.0 (5.2.4+ recommended). And i have PHP 5.3.1

Comment: You still need to enable it in php.ini though. Then it will work for you.

Comment: just in my php.ini add extension=intl.so yes?

Comment: I'm on windows and have this line in php.ini; `extension=php_intl.dll`

Answer (score 9):

I recently blogged about Zend Framework 2 and how all the i18n, l10n and locale settings work. This might be interesting for you, too, as the locale used can be set up by many ways.

Read about it: [Zend Framework 2 - translate, i18n, locale](http://samminds.com/2012/09/zend-framework-2-translate-i18n-locale/)

Personally i go with the following approach and then - depending on your structure - you may add locales from either database, session or cookies or whatever ;)

```
<?php
namespace FileManager;

use Zend\Mvc\ModuleRouteListener;

class Module
{
    public function onBootstrap($e)
    {
        $translator = $e->getApplication()->getServiceManager()->get('translator');
        $translator
          ->setLocale(\Locale::acceptFromHttp($_SERVER['HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE']))
          ->setFallbackLocale('en_US');
    }

    //...
}
```

Comment: this method \Locale::acceptFromHttp($_SERVER['HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE']) returns only the "fr" or "en" and not the complete locale: "fr_FR" or "en_GB".

Comment: Looks like you recently changed your blog software, or deleted that post, @sam!

Comment: @TwoWholeWorms thanks for notifying me, problem with the cache module. It's working again.